# Control size / styling of QToolButton (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a drop down "details" display for a dialog using a QToolButton (to toggle show / hide) and a QTextEdit (to show the information). I am switching between a right arrow (hidden) and down arrow (shown) to indicate the current state of the display.

```
    # Create a button to toggle the details frame.              
    self._detailsbutton = QToolButton()                                     
    self._detailsbutton.setCheckable(True)                                  
    self._detailsbutton.setChecked(False)                                   
    self._detailsbutton.setArrowType(Qt.RightArrow)                         
    self._detailsbutton.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)           
    self._detailsbutton.toggled.connect(self.showDetails)
```

By default the QToolButton is pretty large.

[image]

I have been trying to find a way to shrink the size of this button. The only promising thing I've found is the QWidget.setFixedSize method, but using this causes the tool button arrow to look off center and clipped.

```
    # Create a button to toggle the details frame.              
    self._detailsbutton = QToolButton()                                     
    self._detailsbutton.setCheckable(True)                                  
    self._detailsbutton.setChecked(False)                                   
    self._detailsbutton.setArrowType(Qt.RightArrow)                         
    self._detailsbutton.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)           
    self._detailsbutton.setFixedSize( 10, 10 )                              
    self._detailsbutton.toggled.connect(self.showDetails)
```

[image]

I tried setting the size to different values (5 - 15), but the arrow doesn't center correctly for any of them. Does anyone know how I can scale down the size of the tool button while keeping the arrow centered? I would also be interested in finding out how to control the size of the displayed arrow.

As always, if someone has a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to turn off the border around the button, and just show the naked arrow against a grey background.

Comment: May not be the simplest way, but you can subclass QToolButton and reimplement paintEvent (I know the PySide docs have some examples here, which carry over straightforwardly to PyQt)

Answer (score 2):

on linux and windows 10 toolbutton and arrow are shown correctly, so i can't reproduce your issue. But as shown by your png's only the size of the toolbutton is changed, the arrow seems to have the old size.

As written [in documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#details) the size of the toolbutton can be adjusted by setIconSize. So you can try, this is working on linux

```
self._detailsbutton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(int, int))
```

If that's not working try to set the iconSize according to the toolbuttons size

```
bw = 10                                 # buttonWidth
iw = int(bw*.0.8)                       # iconWidth
self._detailsbutton.setFixedSize( bw, bw )
self._detailsbutton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(iw,iw))
```

turn off border around the button by

```
self._detailsbutton.setStyleSheet('border: none;')
```